# How optimal dynamically to generate multi-column text styles

Tags: javascript, css, multiple-columns

I have the number of columns is specified by a query string.

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
var columns=getParameterByName('col');
```

Now I need to dynamically generate styles.
I tried to do like this:

```
document.querySelector('.wrapper_sport').style.mozColumnCount=columns;
document.querySelector('.wrapper_sport').style.webkitColumnCount=columns;
document.querySelector('.wrapper_sport').style.ColumnCount=columns;
```

For me it is bad code.I also want to define other styles ....column-gap,column-rule other.
Advise the best way to generate styles.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can wrote styles for class (example "columns") in your CSS file and add this class in JS when you need.

```
.wrapper_sport{
same style
}
.wrapper_sport.columns{
-moz-column-count: 3;
-moz-column-gap: 50px;
-webkit-column-count: 3;
-webkit-column-gap: 50px;
column-count: 3;
column-gap: 50px;
}
```

Comment: ok,if I need from 1 to 10 colums then i must created 10 styles classes? Any alternative?